# Passing values from controller to views rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

New to rails here. I receive an null value on the value of @name it receives #Profile::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00007f3dec9ae7b0

---

Controller

```
 def index
     @name = Profile.where(session[:id])
 end
```

---

index html

```
   <%= form_for :value, url: value do |f| %>
   <!------ This form_for is for the post/create into the another table---->
      <%= f.hidden_field :message, :value => @name %>
```

---

I have a form_for which post a value into another table and included a hidden_field to insert to another table. Basically I want to retrieve the name of the person and assign the name to the :value => @name. But it gives a different value. Thanks a lot for you help

Comment: `where(session[:id])` makes no sense. Did you mean `find(session[:id])`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To slightly over simplify, `where` returns *multiple* values, in the form of an ActiveRecord relation.

You want to find a *single* value, so use `.first` on the result of your `where` or use `find`.